# Booting an embedded device from a saved snapshot every time?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, boot, bootloader

I'd like to know if there is any information out there on booting linux from a saved snapshot upon every boot.

I have an embedded system running linux with some basic applications. When there is nothing to do it will enter hibernate mode, suspending to flash storage and resuming from there later. However, my application does not require me to keep the exact state the device was in, and to save on time and power consumption as well as not wearing out the flash I thus want to resume from a fixed image instead of saving the current state.

I suppose one can do a fresh boot each time, but I'm having issues with long booting times and high energy consumption during boot.

I was unable to find anything on the subject by searching so I'd appreciate it if someone could enlighten me or point me in the right direction.

Is it easiest to write a Linux kernel module implementing it myself, or is there some finished code available out there?

Comment: You could halt the device, read the snapshot of memory to a file and each time write this snapshot and start the device. Is that feasible for you?

Comment: @dpc.ucore.info, How would that be different from the normal hibernate? What I want is to not have to write the snapshot each time that it goes into hibernation

Comment: I mean "halt" as in "JTAG debugging halt". And store a memory to external file (on development host, not target). That would help with a flash. I'm sorry, but your question is poorly written IMO. You only briefly tell what you are trying to do and does not give a clear picture: what tools are you using etc. What do you mean by "device"? The whole embedded system or just one device (as uart, or usb device, etc.)